# Regex in python

Tags: python, regex

How to write regex for string like:

```
'$12.78..'
```

I googled and found "re" is the Python module to do it using `import re`.

But I couldn't figured out the exact way to do it.

Comment: The exact language of regex's you are trying to parse is also unclear.

Comment: import re  re.match(^$.)

Comment: do not forget to escape the dollar sign, as it matches the end of line.

Comment: naming a variable "tuple" is not a good idea as it is a Python type. And re.match returns None or a match object not a tuple, so the variable name is misleading.

Comment: s = '$12.78..' re.match('\$(\d*)\.(\d*)',s)

Comment: my bad, i thought of a findall

Answer (score 5):

As a starter:

```
 import re
 print re.match("\$\d\d\.\d+", "$12.1")
 print re.match("\$\d\d\.\d+", "12.1")
 print re.match("\$\d\d\.\d+", "$123.1")
 print re.match("\$\d\d\.\d+", "$12.")
```

If you want to learn more about regular expressions in Python I recommend:

- http://diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/index.html
- http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html
- http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html
- thanks to Stals: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWyoYtvJpe4

Comment: also a google class video about regular expressions: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWyoYtvJpe4

Comment: @Stals: thanks for the hint, did not know that. For other readers: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWyoYtvJpe4